Windows 11 PowerShell Console appearance
In Windows 10 I was able to create a shortcut for running a PowerShell script and I could edit properties on that shortcut to manage the appearance of the console. I could set the font and font size, foreground and background colors (I need black text on a while background) and most importantly I could turn off output wrapping.
With Windows 11 it seems like Microsoft has forced a new combined command line and console, with global settings that can't be managed on a case by case basis. Is that true, or am I missing the new way to do this?

Do you mean PowerShell's shortcut or a PS1 file shortcut?

It's kinda both. It points to the Powershell EXE, and then also a PS1 as an argument, plus arguments related to the console itself as well as arguments for the script. This is an example Target for one of mine.
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -noExit -executionpolicy bypass -file "\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 3.## Dev 3.4.5\Resources\PxUtility_InventorySoftware.ps1" -r:"P -nl Microsoft, iD -lt 2M, T -ne Appx" -o:"O_X"
